# Why does Chrome unescape quotes in URL when calling history.pushState?

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I'm working on a search engine, where the search string can be enclosed by quotes, indicating that the search should be "exact match" (similar to Google).

When I call

```
history.pushState(myState, "My Title", "/search/%22something%22")
```

Chrome puts unescaped quotes into the URL area, which breaks my application on server-side. Other characters, eg. spaces are kept escaped.

I'm not sure if this is true for all browsers, currently have tried only in Chrome.

Does anyone have any idea about this behaviour? What can I do to force leaving the URL as is?